# Share my dbContext with all my repository/service class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on a classic .Net Framework Web API solution.

I have 3 layers. Let's call them

- MVC - with POST, GET, UPDATE, DELETE controllers.
- BIZZ - for business with my service class. My service class are king of repositories with CREATE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE and specific methods.
- DATA - with POCO and definition of DB context.

I will not develop the EF layer. It is a classic Entity Framework project with POCO.Here is a sample of a Service and with BaseService class

```
public abstract class Service : IDisposable
{
    protected DbContext dbContext = new DbContext();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        dbContext.Dispose();        
    }
}
```

Then I have a cart service and a order service. They are similar in their structure so I will only write the code useful for this example.

```
    public class CartService : Service
    {

        public Cart Create(Cart cart)
        {
            // Create the cart
        }

        public Cart Read(Guid id)
        {
            // Read
        }

        public Cart Update(Cart cart)
        {
            // I do some check first then
        }

        public void Delete(Cart cart)
        { 
            // Delete
        }

        public void Checkout(Cart cart)
        { 
            // Validation of cart removed in this example
            dbContext.Cart.Attach(cart);
            cart.DateCheckout = DateTime.UtcNow;
            dbContext.Entry(cart).State = EntityState.Modified; // I think this line can be removed
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
           using (var orderService = new OrderService())
           {
                foreach (var order in cart.Orders)
                {
                     order.DateCheckout = cart.DateCheckout;
                     order.Status = OrderStatus.PD; // pending
                     orderService.Update(order); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class OrderService : Service
    {

        public Cart Create(Cart cart)
        {
            // Create the cart
        }

        public Cart Read(Guid id)
        {
            // Read
        }

        public Cart Update(Cart cart)
        {
            dbContext.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            // More process here...
            return order;
        }

        public void Delete(Cart cart)
        { 
            // Delete
        }
    }
```

So, I have a service, cart service, that call another service, order service. I must work like this because I cannot simply accept the cart and all orders in it as it is. When I save a new order or update an existing order I must create a record in some other tables in other databases. The code is not in my example. So, I repeat I have a service that call another service and then I have 2 dbContext. At best this just create 2 context in memory, at worst this create exception. Exception like you cannot attach an entity to 2 contexts or this entity is not in context.

Well, I would like all my service use the same context. I suppose you will al tell me to use Dependency Injection. Yes, well ok but I don't want, each time I create a new service have to pass the context. I don't want to have to do that:

```
    public void Checkout(Cart cart)
    { 
        // ...
       using (var orderService = new OrderService(dbContext))
       {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

I would like to do something that impact my base service only if possible. A singleton maybe... At this point I can see your face. Yes I know Singleton are soo bad. Yes but i'm doing a IIS Web API. Each request is a new instance. I don't care about the impact of the singleton. And I can load my database by changing the connection string in config file so the benefit of DI is there already. Well, I also know it is possible to have singleton with DI. I just don't know how.

So, what can I do to be sure I share my dbContext with all my services?

Comment: "not having to pass in the context manually" is why we use dependency injection *containers* to automate and further decouple object creation from the point of use

I'm not sure you have options other than "lookup" or "injection" to begin with, so if you absolutely want lookup then... implement lookup in whichever scope you deem appropriate, if you're convinced it's the right scope. (I.e. spans all related operations on the context, but no further.) It's your codebase after all, but I don't think an answer that isn't the two exists.

Comment: The reason why you would use DI (the concept, not a container) here is then the scope for which the context lives becomes *explicit* in your app's code, rather than implicit in how the hosting environment works. But that's not a functional consideration, but one of maintainability. (Making it easier to understand when the context is shared, and easier to change its scope if and when needed.)

Comment: Create service factory, which will create only one DbContext and every time controller ask for another service factory will return new service with same instance of DbContext.

Comment: @millimoose Fully agree and these points. It is just I don't want to implement it by passing my dbContext to all my service everywhere, This will be, actually, a maintenance issue for me.

Comment: Sure, no DI, but the concern of "passing" the context to all your services is something *you* **don't** have to handle; the DI does that.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask but is it possible to have an example of how to implement this DI or Factory pattern with this dbContext situation that must be common to many EF projects? I ask because except perfect tutorial explainign you all this with perfect situation when it come to real case I can find nothing. Is it at this point complex?

Comment: @BastienVandamme - I mean… I honestly don’t know what to advise here that isn’t “actually read the docs/tutorial for any DI container” or working this out for you; this is such a basic use case of DI containers I’m having a hard time believing tutorials wouldn’t cover it. Injecting your controller with service objects that already had all their dependencies set up is literally the main thing they’re for? I’d have half expected the project templates / codegen for EF core to already do this. I’ll give it a shake when I’m at a computer though to see if it fits the scope of an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: This example is not intended to be a "good" one and certainly does not follow best practices, but faced with an existing legacy code base which from your example already suffers from a number of questionable practices, this should get you past the multiple context issues.

Essentially if you're not already using a IoC Container to perform dependency injection then what you need is to introduce a  unit of work to manage the scope of a DbContext where your base Service class provides a DbContext provided by the unit of work. (Essentially a DbContext Registry)

For the unit of work and assuming EF6 I would recommend Mehdime's DbContextScope which is available as a NuGet package. Alternatively you can find the source code on Github and implement something similar without too much trouble. I like this pattern because it leverages the CallContext to serve as the communication layer between the ContextScope (Unit of Work) created by the DbContextScopeFactory and the AmbientDbContextScope. This will probably take a little time to get your head around but it injects very nicely into legacy applications where you want to leverage the Unit of Work and don't have dependency injection.

What it would look like:

In your Service class you would introduce the AmbientDbContextLocator to resolve your DbContext:

```
private readonly IAmbientDbContextLocator _contextLocator = new AmbientDbContextLocator();

protected DbContext DbContext
{
    get { return _contextLocator.Get<DbContext>(); }
}
```

And that's it. Later as you refactor to accommodate Dependency injection, just inject the AmbientDbContextLocator instead of 'new'ing it up.

Then, in your web API controllers where you are using your services, (not the services themselves) you need to add the DbContextScopeFactory instance..

```
private readonly IDbContextScopeFactory _contextScopeFactory = new DbContextScopeFactory();
```

Lastly, in your API methods, when you want to call your services, you need to simply use the ContextScopeFactory to create a context scope. The AmbientDbContextLocators will retrieve the DbContext from this context scope. The context scope you create with the factory will be done in a `using` block to ensure your contexts are disposed. So, using your Checkout method as an example, it would look like:

In your Web API [HttpPost] Checkout() method:

```
using (var contextScope = _contextScopeFactory.Create())
{
    using(var service = new CartService())
    {
        service.Checkout();
    }
    contextScope.SaveChanges();
}
```

Your cart service Checkout method would remain relatively unchanged, only instead of accessing dbContext as a variable (`new DbContext()`) it will access the DbContext property which gets the context through the context locator.

The Services can continue to call DbContext.SaveChanges(), but this isn't necessary and the changes will not be committed to the DB until the contextScope.SaveChanges() is called. Each service will have its own instance of the Context Locator rather than the DbContext and these will be dependent on you defining a ContextScope to function. If you call a Service method that tries to access the DbContext without being within a `using (var contextScope = _contextScopeFactory.Create())` block you will receive an error.  This way all of your service calls, even nested service calls (CartService calls OrderService) will be interacting with the same DbContext instance.

Even if you just want to read data, you can leverage a slightly faster DbContext using `_contextScopeFactory.CreateReadOnly()` which will help guard against unexpected/disallowed calls to `SaveChanges()`.

Answer (score 2):

When using the ASP.NET Core stack, the tutorial for using EF with it defaults to using DI to provide your DB context, just not with a service layer. That said, it actually does the right thing for this out of the box. I'll give a brief rundown of the bare minimum necessary for this to work, using whatever the latest versions of ASP.NET Core Web API and EF Core were on NuGet at the time of writing.

First, let's get the boilerplate out of the way, starting with the model:

#### `Models.cs`

```
public class ShopContext : DbContext
{
    public ShopContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) {}

    // We add a GUID here so we're able to tell it's the same object later.
    public string Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Cart
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then some bare-bones services:

#### `Services.cs`

```
public class CartService
{
    ShopContext _ctx;

    public CartService(ShopContext ctx)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
        Console.WriteLine($"Context in CartService: {ctx.Id}");
    }

    public async Task<List<Cart>> List() => await _ctx.Carts.ToListAsync();

    public async Task<Cart> Create(string name)
    {
        return (await _ctx.Carts.AddAsync(new Cart {Name = name})).Entity;
    }
}

public class OrderService
{
    ShopContext _ctx;

    public OrderService(ShopContext ctx)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
        Console.WriteLine($"Context in OrderService: {ctx.Id}");
    }

    public async Task<List<Order>> List() => await _ctx.Orders.ToListAsync();

    public async Task<Order> Create(string name)
    {
        return (await _ctx.Orders.AddAsync(new Order {Name = name})).Entity;
    }

}
```

The only notable things here are: the context comes in as a constructor parameter as God intended, and we log the ID of the context to verify when it gets created with what.

Then our controller:

#### `ShopController.cs`

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ShopController : ControllerBase
{
    ShopContext _ctx;
    CartService _cart;
    OrderService _order;

    public ShopController(ShopContext ctx, CartService cart, OrderService order)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Context in ShopController: {ctx.Id}");
        _ctx = ctx;
        _cart = cart;
        _order = order;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        var carts = await _cart.List();
        var orders = await _order.List();
        return (from c in carts select c.Name).Concat(from o in orders select o.Name);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task Post(string name)
    {
        await _cart.Create(name);
        await _order.Create(name);
        await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

As above, we take the context as a constructor parameter to triple-check it's what it should be; we also need it to call `SaveChanges` at the end of an operation. (You can refactor this out of controllers if you want to, but they'll work just fine as units of work for now.)

The part that ties this together is the DI configuration:

#### `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    // Use whichever provider you have here, this is where you grab a connection string from the app configuration.
    services.AddDbContext<ShopContext>(options =>
        options.UseInMemoryDatabase("Initrode"));
    services.AddScoped<CartService>();
    services.AddScoped<OrderService>();
}
```

`AddDbContext()` defaults to registering a DbContext to be created per-request by the container. Web API provides the `AddControllers` method that puts those into the DI container, and we also register our services manually.

The rest of `Startup.cs` I've left as-is.

---

Starting this up and opening `https://localhost:5001/shop` should log something like:

> Context in CartService: b213966e-35f2-4cc9-83d1-98a5614742a3
>   Context in OrderService: b213966e-35f2-4cc9-83d1-98a5614742a3
>   Context in ShopController: b213966e-35f2-4cc9-83d1-98a5614742a3

with the same GUID for all three lines in a request, but a different GUID between requests.

---

A little additional explanation of what goes on above:

Registering a component in a container (using `Add()` and such above) means telling the container those components exist and that it should create them for you when asked, as well as what identifiers they're available under and how to create them. The defaults for this are more or less "make the component available as its class, and create it by calling its one public constructor, passing other registered components into it" - the container looks at the constructor signature to figure this out.

"Scoped" in an ASP.NET Core app means "per-request." I think in this case one could also use services with a transient lifetime - a new one created every time it's needed, but they'll still get the same `DbContext` as long as they're created while handling the same request. Which one to do is a design consideration; the main constraint is that you can't inject shorter-lived components into longer-lived components without having to use more complex techniques, which is why I favour having all components as short-lived as possible. In other words, I only make things longer-lived when they actually hold some state that needs to live for that time, while also doing that as sparingly as possible because state bad. (Just recently I had to refactor an unfortunate design where my services were singletons, but I wanted my repositories to be per-request so as to be able to inject the currently logged in user's information into the repository to be able to automatically add the "created by" and "updated by" fields.)

You'll note that with support for doing things this way being built-in to both ASP.NET Core and EF Core, there's actually very little extra code involved. Also, the only thing needed to go from "injecting a context into your controllers" (as the tutorial does) to "injecting a context into services that you use from your controllers" is adding the services into DI - since the controller and context are already under DI, anything new you add can be injected into them and vice versa.

---

This should give you a quick introduction into how to make things "just work" and shows you the basic use case of a DI container: you declaratively tell it or it infers "this is an X", "this is an Y", "this is a Z and it needs to be created using an X and a Y"; then when you ask the container to give you a Z, it will automagically first create an X and Y, then create Z with them. They also manage the scope and lifetime of these objects, i.e. only create one of a type for an API request. Beyond that it's a question of experience with them and familiarity with a given container - say Ninject and Autofac are much more powerful than the built-in one - but it's variations on the same idea of declaratively describing how to create an object possibly using other objects (its dependencies) and having the container "figure out" how to wire things together.